# Why does Firefox (version 71.0 (64-bit)) indicate “weak encryption” but Google Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.88) does not?

Tags: tls, web-browser, chrome, firefox

I read that Mozilla uses its own trust certificate store but does "weak encryption" have anything to do with whether the browser trusts the certificate?

Has it got anything to do with the signature algorithm or signature hash algorithm?

Firefox Screenshot 1:

[image: Printscreen 1 of Firefox]

Firefox Screenshot 2:

[image: Printscreen 2 of Firefox]

Firefox Screenshot 3:

[image: Printscreen 3 of Firefox]

Chrome Screenshot 1:

[image: Printscreen 1 of Chrome]

Chrome Screenshot 2:

[image: Printscreen 2 of Chrome]

Comment: Did you check [SSL Labs' test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=startutor.sg)? I'm guessing Firefox either doesn't like TLS 1.0, or doesn't like CBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... does "weak encryption" have anything to do with whether the browser trust the certificate? Has it got anything to do with the signature algorithm or signature hash algorithm?

The weak encryption has nothing to do with the certificate:
The hash algorithm used for the certificates signature is SHA-256 which is perfectly fine. The signature is also done with a RSA key of 2048 bit (can be seen in the intermediate CA, which is not shown by you) which is also perfectly fine.

Instead like said in [the other answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/223198/37315) the weak encryption refers to the use of TLS 1.0 with a CBC cipher. Note that unlike Chrome Firefox does not use RSA key exchange with this site but instead DHE (the cipher is `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`), so the information regarding the weak key exchange in the other answer does not apply to Firefox.

To determine what exactly Firefox considers weak I was trying the same cipher with the same length of the DH parameters (1024 bit) as used by the original server but changed the TLS version. It looks like with TLS 1.2 Firefox 70.0.1 considers the encryption strong and only when disabling TLS 1.2 it considers the encryption weak since it now has to use TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.0.

Comment: `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` isn't ECDHE, it does fall short in the ways Firefox lists

Comment: @BenVoigt: DHE provides forward secrecy, contrary to RSA key exchange. *".., it does fall short in the ways Firefox lists"* - do you have details (preferable with source) on what exactly Firefox considers weak or is this statement just your feeling on how Firefox behaves?

Comment: `RSA` is still part of that cipher.  Firefox is recommending to use Elliptic Curve cryptography instead of modular exponentiation.

Comment: @BenVoigt: *"RSA is still part of that cipher"* -  This "RSA" in the cipher stands for RSA based __authentication__ and relates to the type of public key in the certificate. This is still the predominant form of authentication and still considered secure with the proper key length (at least 2048). Please show me any recommendation by Mozilla or any other reliable source which considers RSA based __authentication__ (i.e. the use of RSA certificates) weak.

Comment: It's the DHE key exchange which is considered weak.  DHE uses modular exponentiation in a prime field, aka RSA.  See https://www.digicert.com/blog/google-plans-to-deprecate-dhe-cipher-suites/  Diffie-Hellman (DH) and the ephemeral version (DHE) specify the order of operations for key exchange.  RSA vs ECC specifies the crypto inside the individual operations.

Comment: I do apologize for mixing up the Chrome developer output with the Firefox messages to the user.  But that site is forcing weak crypto with both browsers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I cannot follow your arguments. The link from DigiCert you provide and the more detailed post on chromium-dev referenced from this does not claim that DHE is weak in general as you do but that using  1024 bit is no long term solution either (see weakdh.org for more). While ECDHE is definitely better than DHE this is because of shorter keys and much faster computation and not because DHE in general is weak.

Comment: I don't see why you are concluding that the cipher used for key exchange with Firefox is safe.  The RSA certificate is paired with a 2048 bit private key, but that doesn't imply that the DHE is using a 2048 bit group.

Comment: @BenVoigt: *"... the cipher used for key exchange..."* - this does not even make sense. Key exchange is part of the cipher and not "a cipher is used for key exchange" (an *algorithms* is used). Apart from that I'm not claiming that the currently used cipher is safe, I'm claiming that DHE is not weak in general but might be weak depending on the parameters used. And this is actually the same with ECDHE.

Comment: You claimed "the information regarding the weak key exchange in the other answer does not apply to Firefox".   The way I understood that, you meant "The key exchange is weak in Chrome.  In Firefox, due to a different cipher, the key exchange is not weak.".  If you meant something other than that, perhaps you can rewrite that sentence for clarity and then we can clean up this mess of comments.

Comment: And my previous comment should have said "the parameters specified by the cipher for use in key exchange"... "cipher used for key exchange" was a mis-abbreviation

Comment: @BenVoigt: To end the discussion see my updated answer: Firefox does not care about DHE vs. ECDHE and does not even care about CBC or the key length of 128 in this case but only cares about TLS 1.2 vs. TLS 1.0 (or TLS 1.1).

Comment: *"The key exchange is weak in Chrome. In Firefox, due to a different cipher, the key exchange is not weak."* - that's what I still mean. A cipher is a collection of algorithms and their specific use, i.e. it defines what method is used for key exchange, for authentication, for encryption ... . The different cipher in Firefox defines a different algorithms for the key exchange (DHE vs. RSA) and this algorithm is not considered weak in general. It can be weak with the wrong parameters (like only using 512 bit) but this is true for ECDHE too - there are weak curves too.

Answer (score 1):

While Chrome doesn't throw a warning in main the user interface, here are the warnings shown in the developer console:

> #### Connection - obsolete connection settings
>
> The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.0, RSA, and AES_128_CBC with HMAC-SHA1.
>
> - TLS 1.0 is obsolete. Enable TLS 1.2 or later.
> - RSA key exchange is obsolete. Enable an ECDHE-based cipher suite.
> - AES_128_CBC is obsolete. Enable an AES-GCM-based cipher suite.

Being obsolete doesn't mean it's broken, that might be why Chrome doesn't feel the need to tell the user directly about it.

Comment: "Being obsolete doesn't mean it's broken" is true, but ignoring the fact that in the screenshot posted, Firefox explicitly says it is broken.